# Swift performSegueWithIdentifier delay

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have the following situation: I do a check when user touches screen, to check if it matches some bounds `if menuButton.frame.contains(coordinates) {`

Then, I try to push a segue like this `performSegueWithIdentifier(menuButton.whichButton(menuButton.tag), sender: self)` 
 My problem is that the first time the segue performs, it has a huge delay (about 3-4 sec). Afterwards, everything runs as it should. I did check for main thread and I am in the main thread. 
 Can you please help me?

Comment: Why are you checking coordinates rather than a) using actions for existing buttons/controls or b) defining gestures?

Comment: I dont think this makes that big of a difference, besides it used to work just fine. This is how my particular project needs to behave, I have some custom views not buttons, but i might try to see if by adding a button will make things faster. EDIT just checked, same delay when adding a button so it's not that

Comment: Performing a segue will load the `xib/nib` file.  Is it huge (by some UI standard)?

Comment: No, its just a normal iphone generic storyboard with constraints (disabled classes kept only iphone)

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, as strange as it may appear, it was related with the fonts. I added some fonts, selected them in interface builder, but of course I didn't check the target membership. So the system was looking for them, I think, before reverting to default font, thus creating the lag. I hope it helps someone at some point.

Comment: Yeh, your question did inspire me to look at what I changed in the storyboard rather than codewise

Comment: I was just about to throw my computer out the window when I found this answer. The other day, without any changes to how my navigation works, my app started taking about 4 seconds to segue. Turns out I had deleted a font that was still being set in UI builder (even though it was being overridden in that VC's viewDidLoad). I'm extremely glad I found this before I wasted more hours banging my head against my desk.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to run on a device or only in the simulator? Just to make sure...
You can try this too:

> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
>                      self.performSegueWithIdentifier(mysegueIdentifier, self)
>     })

Comment: I did try it on device, same delay. I also did do the async part, main thread checking and so on .. nothing works so far and is driving me nuts!

Comment: This is a good suggestion as you should always update UI on the main thread, but without code from the OP, it's difficult to diagnose the delay further.